# keep track of form data when same from used for another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a page where the mother or father can add family members, they all need to fill out the same form, so I thought I would just use 1 form.

However that has created a small problem, as I want the person setting up the profiles to be able to double check any of the forms data, by clicking on the family members face.

see example of what I have so far.

https://codepen.io/russellharrower/pen/rzxLRj

js

```
var newpetsid = 0;

$(document).on ("click", "div.btn-floating", function () {
 alert(this.id);
 if(this.id === "addnew"){  

 dl= document.getElementById("newpetprofiles");
dl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<div id="'+ newpetsid +'" class="btn-floating btn-large blue waves-effect waves-light"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></div>');
   newpetsid++;
 }

  var morphFAB = $('#overlay');
  morphFAB.toggleClass('visible hidden');
  if (morphFAB.hasClass('visible')) {
    $('#form').addClass('animated slideInUp');
  }else {
    $('#form').removeClass('animated slideInUp');
  }
})
```

html

```
<!-- on Morph FAB Display -->
<div id="newpetprofiles" class="fixed-action-btn">

  <!-- beforebegin -->  
  <div id="overlay" class="blue-grey hidden">  
   <div id="form">
 DEPENDING ON IF IT IS THE ADD BUTTON OR A IMAGE OF THEIR KID A DIFFENT FORM SHOULD SHOW.
</div>
  </div>


   <!-- afterbegin -->
  <div class="btn-floating btn-large blue waves-effect waves-light">
    <img src="https://ipet.xyz/template/images/russellharrower.jpg"/>
  </div>
   <!-- beforeend -->
  <div id="addnew" name"addnew" class="btn-floating btn-large blue waves-effect waves-light">
    <i class="material-icons">
    add
  </i>
  </div>
  <!-- afterend -->
</div>
```

css

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.fixed-action-btn {
  top:3%;
  right: calc(50%);
  left: calc(50% - auto);
  margin:0 auto !important;
  padding: 0;
  #overlay {
    position: absolute;
  //  text-align:center;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    &.hidden {
      height: 55px;
      width: 55px;
      border-radius: 0%;
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    &.visible {
       position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right:0;
      left:0;
      // bottom: 0;
      height: 100%;
      color:#FFF;
      text-align:left;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 0;
      //transform: scale(25);
    }
    h2 {
      position: fixed;
      transform: scale(1) !important;
      top: 100px;
    }
  }
}
#form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  //display: none;
  // transform: translateY(200px);
  // display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
 // transition: 0.5s ease;

  .btn-floating.red {
    display: block;
  }
```

}

I know that all the data will need to be saved to an array, one that can grow as the person who is setting the profiles up.

and then once all profiles are completed then send it to the server with a xmlhttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array for family members (fm in the future);

```
var members = [];
```

Then on each add event create a object with empty values for the form and push it to members (you can use the length of the array before pushing the fm for the div's id)

```
dl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<div id="'+ members.length +'" ...<more code>'
var newMember = {aProperty: '', anotherProperty: ''};
members.push(newMember);
```

Open the form right before adding a fm using as Id the length of members, else set the id to the id of the family member clicked

```
if(this.id === "addnew"){
  var memberId = members.length;
  <... rest of the add new logic ...>
} else {
  var memberId = this.id;
}
```

Fill the inputs values using the fm id to search on the array

```
member = members[memberId];
$('input.a-property').val(member.aProperty);
```

When saving the form be sure to save the values to the array

```
members[memberId].aProperty = $('input.a-property').val();
```

Comment: Remember to set the memberId var before pushing to the array, that way if the id is 2 the index of the next element will be also 2, otherwise you will push to the array making the length 3 and therefore your id will be 3 but the index of the element will still be 2;